# c++ stringstream conversion error: segmentation fault

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I am having some trouble with a simple function that tries to convert integers to a string. Here is the code:

```
string Problem::indexB(int i, int j, int k){    
    stringstream ss;

    if(i < 10)
        ss << "00";
    else if(i<100)
        ss << "0";
    ss << i;

    if(j < 10)
        ss << "00";
    else if(j<100)
        ss << "0";
    ss << j;

    if(k < 10)
        ss << "00";
    else if(k<100)
        ss << "0";
    ss << k;

    return ss.str();
}
```

The function works fine, but when a make multiple calls it gives me a segmentation fault in some point.

Comment: Which point? What have you done to debug it?

Comment: the error is not in this code fragment. Try using valgrind to locate a stack corruption or similar

Comment: the problem is in the return line. After I call multiple time the function the ".str()" will cause a segmentation fault. Here's the related problem by gdb  

`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

_int_malloc (av=0x7ffff74191c0, bytes=26) at malloc.c:4339
4339 malloc.c: File or directory not found.
 in malloc.c `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me: http://ideone.com/lNOfFZ

Complete working program:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using std::string;
using std::stringstream;

class Problem {
public:
    static string indexB(int i, int j, int k);
};

string Problem::indexB(int i, int j, int k){

    stringstream ss;

    if(i < 10)
        ss << "00";
    else if(i<100)
        ss << "0";
    ss << i;

    if(j < 10)
        ss << "00";
    else if(j<100)
        ss << "0";
    ss << j;

    if(k < 10)
        ss << "00";
    else if(k<100)
        ss << "0";
    ss << k;

    return ss.str();
}

int main() {
    std::cout << Problem::indexB(1, 2, 3) << "\n";
    std::cout << Problem::indexB(400, 50, 6) << "\n";
    std::cout << Problem::indexB(987, 65, 432) << std::endl;
}
```

Segmentation faults often happen a while after the program has run into something with Undefined Behavior, so the stack trace when the error was detected is not necessarily in the same function as the buggy code.

Comment: the problem related by gdb is in the ".str()" function. Here's what i have from the debugger   
`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. _int_malloc (av=0x7ffff74191c0, bytes=26) at malloc.c:4339 4339 malloc.c: File or directory not found. in malloc.c`

Comment: Found it! The problem was that I was storing the results in a vector. After some calls I was clearing the vector and not resizing it again. The problem was not in the return, but in the variable used to store the result. Thank you.